# NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString correct usage

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

My string looks like this:

```
dog-3
dog-2
dog-1
dog0
aaaaaaa
dog1
dog2
dog3
dog4
bbbbbbb
dog5
dog6
dog7
dog8
ccccccc
dog9
dog10
dog11
aaaaaaa
dog12
dog13
dog14
dog15
bbbbbbb
dog16
dog17
dog18
dog19
ccccccc
dog20
dog21
dog22
dog23
```

I am trying to write a regular expression to match a pattern "^aaaaaaa$.+^bbbbbbb$.+^ccccccc"
This is my code where str is described above

```
NSRegularExpression *conflictMarker = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^aaaaaaa$.+^bbbbbbb$.+^ccccccc"
                                                                                    options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators|NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines
                                                                                      error:&error];
[conflictMarker enumerateMatchesInString:str options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)
                                  usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                                        NSRange matchRange = [result range];
                                        NSString *subst = [str substringWithRange:matchRange];
                                        NSInteger a = result.numberOfRanges;

                                        NSLog(@"%ld ", a);

                                        for (NSInteger a = 0; a < result.numberOfRanges; a++) {
                                            NSRange matchRange = [result rangeAtIndex:a];
                                            NSString *subst = [str substringWithRange:matchRange];
                                            NSLog(@"\n%@", subst);

                                        }
    }];
```

My expectation from the above code was to receive two matches; the first match contains a range from "dog1" to "dog8" and second range from "dog12" to "dog19" but I only get 1 match with a range from "dog1" to "dog19".

What am I doing wrong here and how can I correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^aaaaaaa(?:\R(?!(?:bbbbbbb|aaaaaaa|ccccccc)$).*)*\Rbbbbbbb(?:\R(?!(?:aaaaaaa|ccccccc)$).*)*\Rccccccc
```

See the regex demo. Make sure you change the regex options to `options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines` for this pattern to work:

```
NSRegularExpression *conflictMarker = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^aaaaaaa(?:\\R(?!(?:bbbbbbb|aaaaaaa|ccccccc)$).*)*\\Rbbbbbbb(?:\\R(?!(?:aaaaaaa|ccccccc)$).*)*\\Rccccccc"
    options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines
       error:&error];
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `aaaaaaa`  - a string
- `(?:\R(?!(?:bbbbbbb|aaaaaaa|ccccccc)$).*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `\R(?!(?:bbbbbbb|aaaaaaa|ccccccc)$)` - a line break sequence that is not followed with `bbbbbbb`, `aaaaaaa`, or `ccccccc` and the end of a line
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `bbbbbbb` - a string
- `(?:\R(?!(?:aaaaaaa|ccccccc)$).*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `\R(?!(?:aaaaaaa|ccccccc)$)`  - a line break sequence that is not followed with `aaaaaaa` or `ccccccc` and the end of a line
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `ccccccc` -  a string.